# SSRS dynamic text parameter - Create Type Ahead parameters

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have an SSRS report with cascading parameters.

I've been asked to add a parameter which would allow the user to start typing a product name and be prompted with items that match the characters entered.

Is this possible in SSRS? If so, any pointers would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [tutorial](http://tpuch.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/options-for-filtering-parameter-values.html) to create type ahead parameters in SSRS